# sf::Sound functions cause linker errors

Tags: c++, qt, linker, sfml

I have started to use SFML recently. So I downloaded the 2.4.2 Win64 version of the library and started to play around the examples. 
The only problem I have encountered so far is a linker error when I call play/pause/stop on a sf::Sound object. For example for play I get:

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __cdecl
>   sf::Sound::play(void)" (__imp_?stop@Sound@sf@@UEAAXXZ) referenced in
>   function main

Note that I am linking against sfml-audio.lib and can use other objects of the audio lib like AudioBuffers or even other functions of the sf::Sound like setBuffer which is wierd to me.

I am using Qt Creator as IDE so I link in the .pro file like this:

```
LIBS += -LC:/SFML/lib

CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-main -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio-d -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-main-d -lsfml-network-d -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-system-d

INCLUDEPATH += C:/SFML/include
DEPENDPATH += C:/SFML/include
```

Does anyone have a clue on whats happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you link it?

Comment: Dynamically. I have also tried to link with openal32 without any change.

Comment: Recommend adding the linker command line to the question. Most answers can be found within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I solved it just downloading the SFML Master and building the library with CMake + Visual Studio.

The libs/dlls generated that way work flawlessly.